# Why doesn't appending dict(s) to a list using copy() python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to append a dict to a list. I've seen this problem a few times on the site, but the solution presented, using .copy() doesn't seem to fix the issue. Do I need to loop my appending variable too?

```
for page in pages :
  if 'http' in page :
    machineList = []
    machine = getPinballMachine(page, siteURL) # this function returns a dict(ionary) of elements from a webpage
    machineList.append(machine.copy())
print (machineList)
```

Only the final dictionary is printed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are resetting the list to empty every time you go through the loop.  Move the line `machineList = []` outside the loop (before the `for`), so that you create only a single list, before entering the loop.